# AttributeError: None Type object has no attribute 'enter'

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a game where you go through the 9 layers of hell for the purposes of getting through "Learning Python the Hard Way."  However, I just can't figure out why I'm getting a certain error message when I'm trying to go to the next scene in the game:

```
class Scene(object): # class Scene has-a function named enter

    def enter(self): # create enter function
        pass


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('Lust')
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

            current_scene.enter()


class Death(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class Limbo(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print """               In Limbo reside the unbaptized and the virtuous pagans
                who, although not sinful, did not accept Christ.
                Without baptism, they lacked the hope for something
                greater than rational minds can conceive.
                You find yourself within Limbo, even though you weren't
                a Pagan.  How strange!  You look around, and see a man
                that looks like someone important, but you don't know
                who he is.  What do you do?"""
        action = raw_input("> ")
        if raw_input == "Walk around" or raw_input == "walk around":
            print "You walk around for a bit, admiring the scenery.  You get bored quickly."
        elif raw_input == "talk to the man":
            print ""
        else:
            print 'Lust'


class Lust(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class Map(object):

    scenes = { # create a dictionary of the scenes you want to use
        'limbo': Limbo(),
        'lust': Lust(),
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

When I run it, I can go through the first "level" but as soon as I get to the action prompt and enter something, it cancels out with the error code:

```
File "game.py", line 21, in play
  current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

and can't figure out why.

Comment: It means `Map.scenes.get(scene_name)` returned `None` because the scene wasn't found. You'll have to debug what the specific `scene_name` was that caused this.

Comment: You seem to be using the return value of the `scene.enter()` call to determine the next scene. Your `.enter()` methods do not return *anything*, so the next scene name is always going to be `None`. `Map.scenes.get(None)` will return `None` as there is no such key. `print` writes to your console, it does not return. Use `return` for that.

Comment: Your scene is named `'lust'` (lowercase l). You are asking for `'Lust'` (uppercase L).

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.  None of your methods are in the class.

Comment: You are trying to compare the function object with the output: `if raw_input == "Walk around" or raw_input == "walk around":`. I think you meant to use `action` there instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, Martijn!  That fixed it.  On to the next levels! :-)